# Clojure - connections at compile time

Tags: clojure, rabbitmq, leiningen

I have a rabbitMQ connection that seems to be started at compile time (when I type **lein compile**) and then blocks the building of my project. Here are more details on the problem. Let us say this is the clojure file **bla_test.clj**

```
    (import (com.rabbitmq.client ConnectionFactory Connection Channel QueueingConsumer))

    ;; And then we have to translate the equivalent java hello world program using
    ;; Clojure's excellent interop.

    ;; It feels very strange writing this sort of ceremony-oriented imperative code
    ;; in Clojure:

    ;; Make a connection factory on the local host
    (def connection-factory
         (doto (ConnectionFactory.)
           (.setHost "localhost")))

    ;; and get it to make you a connection
    (def connection (.newConnection connection-factory))

    ;; get that to make you a channel
    (def channel (. connection createChannel))


   ;;HERE I WOULD LIKE TO USE THE SAME CONNECTION AND THE SAME CHANNEL INSTANCE AS OFTEN AS 
   ;; I LIKE
    (dotimes [ i 10 ]
      (. channel basicPublish "" "hello" nil (. (format "Hello World! (%d)" i) getBytes)))
```

The clojure file above is part of a bigger clojure program that I build using **lein**. My problem is that when I compile with "lein compile", a connection is done because of the line  `(def connection (.newConnection connection-factory))` and then the compilation is stopped! How can I avoid this? Is there a way to compile without building connection? How can I manage to use the same instance of channel over several calls coming from external components?

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,
Horace

Comment: Have you tried using Langohr - "an idiomatic clojure client for RabbitMQ"? It makes the syntax a lot neater :) http://clojurerabbitmq.info/. I still needed to use the connection-in-atom technique Michal suggested, though.

Comment: Do not put anything with side effects in top level forms. This includes a def that creates a transitory resource like a connection. Anything that has a stateful value should be initialized to an empty state and filled in by an explicit init function that creates anything stateful: connections, external processes, GUI windows, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The Clojure compiler must evaluate all top-level forms, because it can be required to run arbitrary code when expanding calls to macros.

The usual solution to issues like the one you describe is to define a top-level Var holding an object of a dereferenceable type, for example an atom or a promise, and have an initialization function provide the value at runtime. (You could also use a delay and specify the value inline; this is less flexible, since it makes it more difficult to use a different value for testing etc.)